# C# wpf listbox dispaly more than one memberpath

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'd like to understand how to display more values on a listbox using an array as itemsource

So far I can manage with one value, but cannot figure out how to display more than one value:

Code:

```
        listBox1.ItemsSource = toReturn.groups;
        listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
```

`toReturn.Groups` is the array of items; every item has an ID and a Name.

I would like to be able to display both.

Comment: Can I see the rest of the code, I might be able to help you better. I will post an example of what I have used recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string uriGroup = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Group"; //rest based http GET
    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroup); //Load the uri into the xdoc
    var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Group") //descendants of xml query "Group" 
        .Select(n => new
        {
            GroupID = n.Element("GroudID").Value,
            Group = n.Element("GroupName").Value, //first "Group" Sets the column title, second sets the Element to be listed in this case "GroupName" from my service. 

        })
        .ToList();

    dataGridView2.DataSource = groups;
```

Ofcourse I use a dataGrid but I am sure the same can work for listbox? Hope this helps Davide.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a property on your items called display

```
public string Display {
    get {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1}", ID, Name);
    }
}
```

Then just do:

```
listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Display";
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can apply a DataTemplate to your listbox items to gain more control over how they are displayed and not to add redundant properties to your view model. Please find an example here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html